# Error in Upgrade Magento CE version from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0 with composer?

Tags: magento2.3, composer, elasticsearch

I have tried using below command but getting errors when update

Command 1:

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update

Command 2:

> composer update

Output:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires elasticsearch/elasticsearch ~2.0|~5.1 -> satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.0-beta1, v2.0.0-beta2, v2.0.0-beta3, v2.0.0-beta4, v2.0.0-beta5, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.2.0, v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.2, v5.4.0, v5.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

if anyone has an idea help me..!!!

Comment: What is  your elasticsearch version ? Check if your elastic search version is compatible with Magento community-edition 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

**I have also faced this issue for this you have to follow this steps:**

Please Cross Check the requirements, this issue arises once your requirement does not meet with server configurations.

Please cross check your PHP version and all other requirement with this link : [Click Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Also if this not resolved, First Backup your Vendor Folder then Delete it, After run Composer commands such as

```
composer install
composer update
```